# Using XSL For-Each with Parameters?

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to do a XSL transformation on an XML document of all the bus routes and bus stops within my city. In doing so I'm using a for-each select that selects all the "stop" nodes that contain the route number I'm passing in as a parameter.

When I go to run my program, none of the values seem to be getting selected and I am wondering if my syntax is invalid or can you not use parameters in an xsl:for-each select statement?

Here is my xsl:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:param name="route_num"></xsl:param>
  <xsl:param name="num_stops" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:for-each select="allstops/stop[contains(routes,$route_num)]">
      <xsl:sort select="@number"/>
        <tr>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@number"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="@name"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="location/latitude"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="location/longitude"/></td>
        <td><xsl:value-of select="routes"/></td>
       </tr>
    </xsl:for-each>
    <!-- ... -->
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

And here is a sample of the XML:

```
<stop number="20" name="Adelaide &amp; Ada NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9742886</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2252341</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>16</routes>
</stop>
```

So lets say an XML node contains a route of 16, it should go through all the nodes and pull the data into the  fields I have set up, unless my syntax is wrong with the XSL should it not?

EDIT: the routes tag can contain multiple route numbers, which is why I have been using contains:

```
<stop number="408" name="Clarence &amp; King St NB">
    <location>
      <latitude>42.9835093</latitude>
      <longitude>-81.2471596</longitude>
    </location>
    <routes>05, 09, 12, 19, 23</routes>
</stop>
```

EDIT #2: XML has no namespaces.

Comment: If there is any chance at all to change the *"routes can be a comma-delimited list"* part then by all means change it. If you're stuck with it, at least use something that avoids false positives (i.e. 6 also matching 16): `contains(concat(',', translate(routes, ' ', ''), ','), contcat(',', $route_num, ','))`. Yes, that's ugly, but that's direct a consequence of using XML wrong.

Comment: Other than the problem of potential false positives explained above by Tomalak, there is no reason why your select statement should not work. That is, no reason that can be seen from the **partial** code you have posted. Did you check that the parameter is successfully passed to the stylesheet?

Comment: Well that is basically all there is too it. An XSLT transform being done in C# written to a WebBrowser control. It seems that it is not even entering the for-each with my select statement. Could it be the template match?

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/jyyiVhy/1

Comment: It must be something to do with me writing to my WebBrowser control, because its completely skipping the xsl:for-each in my XSLT.

Comment: Check if the XPath in your for-each is actually selecting something (from the code you posted, `allstops` is the root element, unless something before the `for-each` (such as another for-each) changes the context.)

Answer (score 0):

The contains() function works with strings, not with nodes. What you need here is a simple node-set comparison:

```
<xsl:for-each select="allstops/stop[routes=$route_num]">
```

Comment: Well some stops have multiple routes that pass through them, such that the routes tag may look like <routes>16, 31, 42</routes>

Comment: @AaronG. It *should* look like `<routes><route>16</route><route>31</route><route>42</route></routes>` then. You have XML here, so don't use it like a CSV file.

Comment: This isn't my XML file, it is a generated XML file by the London City Transit Commission. I'm merely interpreting it and trying to use XSLT on it.

Comment: @AaronG. Please edit your question (again) and include an **exact example** of multiple routes.

Comment: @AaronG. Don't forget to include any namespaces the XML might have.

Answer (score 0):

`contains()` is a string function (i.e. `'foo'` contains `'o'`). You're using it wrong, you probably want `allstops/stop[routes = $route_num]`.

Other than that - yes, it's possible to use parameter values or variables in XPath expressions, the `<xsl:for-each>` will use whatever the XPath returns.

From your example alone it's not possible to tell where the error in your XPath is. Build the expression again, trying to find out where it fails.